# Tesseract for WinRT UWP

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, tesseract

I need to use Tesseract on a Windows 10 app for phones. Already found an intent made by [Yoisel](https://github.com/yoisel/tesseract_winrt) . I've tried to build the project for test, but i'm kinda new to Visual Studio dependencies and usage.

What i've done so far is to open the tesseract_winrt.sln on the VS2015 folder. 
After that i copied leptonica project to root directory of tesseract_winrt so it can be loaded inside the solution. Once that everything is loaded i click build solution and get this errors:

[image]

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong or how to properly set the dependencies

Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are now binaries for the project that you can use:

https://github.com/yoisel/tesseract_winrt/releases/tag/v0.1-alpha

It is a set of Visual Studio Extension SDKs, you can install the one for UWP projects on your system and add a reference to it in your project using the "Extensions" tab:

[image]

*Disclaimer: This project was merely a proof of concept and I strongly recommend **not to use it as is** in a production scenario*